# Message passing inter process communication

Tags: operating-systems, message-passing

I was reading a book on OS by Galvin. I well understood that blocking send will wait until it has loaded the message into the kernel buffer. In contrast, the non-blocking send system call will return a check value indicating a successful or unsuccessful event.

Please can someone explain the difference between blocking and non-blocking send system call in the scenario when we are using zero buffer capacity in the kernel? Please answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For concrete questions like this, you better consult not a general operating system book, but the documentation for a specific operating system. And why would there be zero buffer capacity in the kernel?

Comment: Some microkernels (e.g. early QNX Neutrino) don't have kernel buffering. They just copy messages directly between address spaces.

Comment: @Pseudonym can you please explain differnece in blocking and non blocking send with respect to QNX Neutrino.